# Transpose\pivot pair of rows with two columns where one is DateTime and the other Text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge, pivot, sql-server-2014, transpose

I have the following table structure and data:

[image]

Data is ordered ASC and for each `Master Clear` there's a subsequent `Blend Closed`. If there's no subsequent `Blend Closed` then it should receive `NULL`.

Now I'd like to get the following result:

```
Master Clear                Blend Closed
2018-09-17 03:12:03         2018-09-17 10:00:03
2018-09-17 10:37:03         2018-09-18 01:05:02
2018-09-18 04:55:02         2018-09-18 21:51:00
2018-09-18 22:55:00         2018-09-19 03:02:01
.                           .
.                           .
.                           .
2018-09-23 20:10:56         NULL
```

This is getting pairs of rows and moving the `Time` column value to its appropriate `Value` column: `Master Clear` or `Blend Closed`.

I tried to get this data shape but couldn't by any means. Is there any way to achieve this output using T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to assign a row number to each value group, then do a regular pivot query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Time) rn
    FROM [BUR_BLEND].[dbo].[BLEND_START_END_TIMES]
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 'Master Clear' THEN Time END) AS [Master Clear],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Value = 'Blend Closed' THEN Time END) AS [Blend Closed]
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that this answer assumes that the `Master Clear` and `Blend Closed` records always come together in logical pairs, and that there are no gaps.  If not, then we would have to do more work to generate your output.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri Added a demo.